# Control Bluetooth LE device without app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is there any way to control a custom Bluetooth LE device that doesn't require submitting an app to the store? Due to the category the device is considered to fall under, Apple is likely to reject any app specifically for that device. It uses a custom service, characteristic, and protocol that is extremely unlikely to be supported by an existing app.

I considered Web Bluetooth, but it does not work with iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only native apps can work with Core Bluetooth to support BLE.

Probably all you can do is set the category and age rating appropriately and submit your app.